# How to get/put Kotlin Inner Map or Map of map

Tags: kotlin

anyone know how can i "get/put" inner map in kotlin ?

```
var bookDetailsMap: MutableMap<Long, MutableMap<Long, Book>> = mutableMapOf()
```

How can i "put" below book details into the map on above

```
var books: MutableList<Book> = this.bookDao.findAll()
```

Expect the storage will be like >

```
var bookDetailsMap: MutableMap<book.publisherId, MutableMap<book.bookId, Book>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Success to make it this way:

Put Example:

```
var bookDetailsMap : Map<Long, Map<Long, BookDetail>> = hashMapOf()

this.bookDetailsMap = this.bookDao.findAll().groupBy { 
   it.publisherId
}.mapValues { 
   it.value.associateBy { it.bookId} 
}
```

Get Example:

```
var bookDetail : BookDetail = BookDetail ()

if (this.bookDetailsMap .containsKey(this.publisherId)) {
    bookDetail = this.bookDetailsMap [this.publisherId]!![this.bookId]!!
}
```